# How to add parameters to ManyToManyField Django

Tags: django, django-models

Question:

Models.py

Suggest i have got djanog class A:

```
class A(models.Model):
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
code = models.CharField("A", max_length=250)
name = models.CharField(("A"), max_length=250)
body = RichTextField(("A"), max_length=2500, blank=True, null=True)
policy = models.CharField(("A"), max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
```

and i create class B:

```
class B(models.Model):
block = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

In Admin portal, when creating an instance of class B, django chooses the ManyToMany field automatically to search based on name. I would like to add the fields based on the code of class A. Help please, I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance for the tips!

Edit:

Admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin

from .models import A, B

admin.site.register(B)

class AAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['code', 'name',]
    search_fields = ['code', 'name', 'body']


admin.site.register(A, AAdmin)
```

Comment: Please share the `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem just edited.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out by using `raw_id_fields` in `admin.py` :)